# A good way of setting up navigation bar/links in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering what is a good way of setting navigation links for different pages in rails ? Right now what I have breaks. Here is the code

```
_nav.html.erb

<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
    <%if current_page?(:action => 'new') %>
    <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path%></li>
    <%elsif current_page?(:controller => 'home', :action => 'index') %>
    <li><%= link_to "Contact", home_contact_path%></li>
    <%end%>
</ul>
```

So when I do a `<%= render :partial => 'layouts/nav' %>` under `/views/home/index.html.erb` It gives me an error

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"home"}
```

Comment: please provide the output of `rake routes`

Comment: here are the routes -http://pastebin.com/qpdAYDKw

Answer (score 2):

You have no action new in your home controller... Looking at your routes, the only action available is contact...

Try to use helpers (`current_page?(helper)`) instead of `action` + `controller`. Check the `rake routes` to see the helpers.

```
_nav.html.erb

<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
  <%if current_page?(new_user_registration) %> #check the path helper by `rake routes`
    <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path%></li>
  <%elsif current_page?(root_path) %>
    <li><%= link_to "Contact", home_contact_path%></li>
  <%end%>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, what do I have in a helper method? Here is my routes - http://pastebin.com/qpdAYDKw

Comment: I have edited the answer... So, if the current_page is new_user_registration the link will be for the root_path... If the current_page is the root, the link will be for the home contact...

Comment: ah thanks so much. makes sense now :). But current_page? method is suppose to work with controller + action , as show in the api. any specific reason its not? Or was i defining them wrong?

Comment: It was defined wrong... There was no action new for home controller... The new_user_registration refers to action new at registrations controller...